# PyQt5 - Cannot invoke function based on QDialog accepted signal

Tags: python, pyqt5, qdialog, qformlayout

One of the functions of my program is to create a file. 
When the given button is pressed, the user is prompted to enter a name for the file. If the file already exists, they are asked to enter a new name. If not, a QDialog pops up, where the user can input some data to be written in the file. However, I am having trouble with the QDialog accepted signal --> when the user presses "Ok" after inputting the data, nothing happens. Only after the process is repeated a second time, does the QDialog.accepted (in **document.py**) invoke the function to which it is connected. Please refer to my code below:

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from gui import UiMainWindow
from document import Doc
import sys

class Logic(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, UiMainWindow, Doc):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 90, 801, 571))

        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.make_document)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    logic = Logic()
    logic.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**gui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class UiMainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("File Manager")
        MainWindow.resize(1120, 750)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 121, 41))

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("File Manager", "File Manager"))
        self.button1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+ New File"))
```

**document.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from form import Form
import os

class Doc(QInputDialog):
    """Create an doc and populate it based on user input."""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.work_dir = os.path.join("C:\\", "Document Manager", "Work environment")
        self.dialog = Form()

    def make_document(self):
        user_input = QInputDialog()
        active = True
        while active:
            text, ok = user_input.getText(self, "Document name",
                                      "Please enter a file name")
            if ok and text != '':
                self.name = text
                output_path = f"{self.work_dir}" + "\\" + f"{self.name}" + ".pdf"
                if not os.path.exists(output_path):
                    self.open_dialog()
                    self.dialog.accepted.connect(self.do_something)
                    active = False
                else:
                    self.show_popup()
            else:
                active = False

    def open_dialog(self):
        self.dialog.exec_()

    def do_something(self):
        print("Doing something")

    def show_popup(self):
        """Show a pop-up message if invoice name already exists"""
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setWindowTitle("File/folder already exists.")
        msg.setText("The document you are trying to create already exists.")
        x = msg.exec_()
```

**form.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Form(QDialog):
    """Show a pop-up form for the user to input file data."""
    NumGridRows = 3
    NumButtons = 4

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.create_form()
        self.button_box = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok |
                                       QDialogButtonBox.Cancel, self)
        self.button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.formbox)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_box)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Document data input")

    def create_form(self):
        self.formbox = QGroupBox("Please provide data below: ")
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Business name: "), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Customer name: "), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Customer email: "), QLineEdit())
        self.formbox.setLayout(layout)
```

I have researched and tried various solutions, but to no avail. Any help would be truly appreciated!

Comment: I am not PyQT5 expert, but why do you call this `self.dialog.accepted.connect(self.do_something)` inside your logic? This is something to be called once, in the beginning. Not everytime user presses a button or something.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I moved self.dialog.accepted.connect(self.do_something) to the Doc class init method, and it worked :) Thank you very much!